# Facing problem in multiprocessing nested loop and dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

there I am a very beginner level in multiprocessing in python.  I cant re-formulate my code into multi processing

```
def Customer_Merchant_value_pass(minicustomer_list):
    begin=timer()
    sum_val=0
    list_avg_score=[]
    list_category_val=[]
    dict_list=[]
    #Avg_score=0
    with graphdriver.session()as session:
        for i in itertools.islice(minicustomer_list,len(minicustomer_list)):
            for key in list_of_unique_merchants:
                print("Here at list_of_unique_merchants customer value is ",i)
                print("BMCC_Code",key)
                valuelist=list_of_unique_merchants[key]
                #print("Uniquelistfor:",key,valuelist)
                for j in  valuelist:

                    #print("list len",len(valuelist))
                    #print("Here the iner of value list ",i)
                          #print("--------------------------------")
                    #print([i,j])
                    pref_attach_score=Prefer_Attachment_query2([i,j])
                    #print(pref_attach_score)

                    result=session.run(pref_attach_score)
                    for line in result:
                        #print(line["score"])
                        sum_val=sum_val+line["score"]
                    #Avg_score=sum_val/len(valuelist) 


                Totalsumval=sum_val
                print("Totalsum",Totalsumval)
                Avg_score=sum_val/len(valuelist)
                print("Avg_score",Avg_score)
                sum_val=0
                list_avg_score.append(Avg_score)
                list_category_val.append(key)
                avg_score_list=list_avg_score
                category_list=list_category_val


                #print("sumval is now",sum_val)



                #print(result)
            max_dictionary  =MaxValue_calc(i,category_list,avg_score_list) 
            #MaxValue_calc(i,category_list,avg_score_list) 

            print("max_dicitionary",max_dictionary)
            dict_list.append(max_dictionary)
            rowlist=dict_list
            print(rowlist)
            #dict_list=[]
            list_avg_score=[] 
            list_category_val=[]

            #print("rowlist", rowlist)
            #print("list_category_val is now",list_category_val)

            #print("for",i," category AVG scores is now ",category_list)


            #print("list_avg_score is now",list_avg_score)
            #print("for",i," category AVG scores is now ",avg_score_list)



    session.close()
    end=timer()
    print("Total time   :",(end-begin))
    return rowlist 



datalist=Customer_Merchant_value_pass()






def Prefer_Attachment_query2(listval):
    customer_wallet=listval[0]
    merchant_wallet=listval[1]
    #print(x,y)
    prefquery="""MATCH (p1:CUSTOMER {WALLETID: '%s'})
                 MATCH (p2:MERCHANT {WALLETID: '%s'})
                 RETURN gds.alpha.linkprediction.preferentialAttachment(p1, p2,{relationshipQuery: "PAYMENT"}) as score"""%(customer_wallet,merchant_wallet)
    #print(prefquery)
    return prefquery
```

from collections import Counter

```
def MaxValue_calc(customer_wallet,category_code,avg_score):
    print("In MaxValue_calc")
    #print(category_code)
    #print(avg_score)
    #score_dict={"score":avg_score}
    #category_dict={"category":category_code}
    #print(score_dict)
    #print(category_dict)
    #customer_wallet_list=[]
    #customer_wallet_list.append(customer_wallet)
    #customer_wallet=customer_wallet_list
    #customer_wallet_list=[]
    #print("category_code_list",category_code)
    #print("average_score_list",avg_score)
    #print(customer_wallet)
    print(" For Customer",customer_wallet)
    wallet_dictionary=dict(zip(category_code,avg_score))
    print("Wallet dictionary",wallet_dictionary)
    #top2score=heapq.nlargest(2, wallet_dictionary, key=wallet_dictionary.get)

    #print(wallet_dictionary)
    #print(wallet_dictionary)
    content=Counter(wallet_dictionary)
    topscore=content.most_common(3)
    top2value_dict=dict(topscore)
    print("Top values",top2value_dict)
    top2value_dict.update({'WALLET_ID':customer_wallet})
    #score
    return top2value_dict


#print(top2value_dict)
#print(type(top2value_dict))
#print( mydataframe)
#print(content)
```

This code generates a list but takes a huge time in processing for larger values. I tried  this code for parallelism

```
import concurrent.futures
with  concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    f1=executor.submit(Customer_Merchant_value_pass,minicustomer_list)
    datalist=f1.result()
```

This worked but still could not use full core of my CPU. but how could use proper parallism

```
Here i iterates over  a list
key iterates over a dictionary of lists and extract value
j iterates over elements of extracted lists
```

so the workflow is Customer_Merchant_value function  process list mini customer list, a dictionary of lists, and  the  element from extracted lists from dictionary.  then  for each element, it calls Prefer_Attachment_query2([i,j]. where i is the element from customer list and j is an element from merchant list. this function dynamically pushes query into neo4j. and return a score. After getting the score average value is calculated. Then  it calls MaxValue_calc  function for  fetching  largest 3  average score. so it takes customer list number, category list which is actually list of keys in dictionary and list of average_score list. and it returns largest key wise average_score. then it will return a data list

Comment: You need to pass an iterable to executor.map as the second argument.  Without refactoring your code and properly executing it in a subprocess, you will get exactly the same result, or actually a bit worse, as your subprocess needs to transmit results back to the main process.   You will need to separate reading and chunking of data and the processing part. Without knowing what this does I cannot give a working example. Now you expect something to automatically transform itself to parallel processing but it is not that simple - you need to make it parallel first.

Comment: let me give you the code example then. @Hannu i am editing it